# Can I add tags to messaging spans based on message header values using Spring Cloud Sleuth?

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Spring Cloud Sleuth to send spans to zipkin when a Spring Boot application sends a message (to RabbitMQ).

I would like to customize the information sent to zipkin to include some extra tags that are populated from certain headers of the outgoing Message e.g. the `myCustomTag` below.

```
"traceId": "9fc1f35070446800",
"parentId": "033b24f12d5fe4e8",
"id": "fea24862c3e1f374",
"kind": "PRODUCER",
"name": "send",
"timestamp": 1609943208647127,
"duration": 1407,
"localEndpoint": {
  "serviceName": "foo-service",
  "ipv4": "10.204.71.17"
},
"remoteEndpoint": {
  "serviceName": "broker"
},
"tags": {
  "channel": "fooEventsChannel",
  "myCustomTag": <some value extracted from the "Bar" header of the outgoing message>
}
```

Is it possible to do this using Sleuth/brave? It feels like a messaging equivalent of registering (e.g.) a bean of type `brave.http.HttpRequestParser` but I couldn't see an obvious way forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`TagValueResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-annotations-advanced-tag-setting) or a [`MessageSpanCustomizer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#customizing-messaging-spans), see the docs for the details.

Comment: Thanks - I think MessageSpanCustomizer seems like the right way to go, but that looks like it is new to 2.2.7 which is targeted for the Ilford release of Spring Cloud. 

Is it safe to mix 2.2.7 Sleuth with Hoxton.SR9?

Comment: @wabrit Ilford (2020.0.0) is for Spring Cloud Sleuth 3.0.0, see [Spring Cloud 2020.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes). [Hoxton SR9](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Hoxton-Release-Notes)  brings in 2.2.6, I think you should be able to use 2.2.7 with Hoxton.

Comment: Thank you that seemed to work fine for me - declaring Hoxton.SR9 + default version of spring-cloud-starter-zipkin, but with explicit 2.2.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT overrides for spring-cloud-sleuth-core and spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin.

One other minor point - the `MessageSpanCustomizer` example in the documentation linked above is I think not correct; both overriden methods should have return type and first parameter type of `SpanCustomizer`.

Comment: @wabrit Could you please file an issue under https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues? Also, if you want to fix it and contribute, please write a comment in the issue and I will assign it to you. :)

Comment: Thanks - new issue for docs is https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1818